# Change default terminal color

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, osx, colors

I often have several SSH terminals open on different servers, and I am looking for a way to keep track of them more easily.  I use MacOS Terminal app.  I have already customized the prompt on each machine like this:

```
export PS1="\[\e[1;38;5;160m\]\[\e[48;5;16m\][\u@\h \W]\[\e[0m\]$ "
```

This makes the prompt foreground and background unique for each machine.  But I would like to also change the default background color for all text.  If I omit the `\e[0m` reset command then I can add colors here, however this will be reset the next time I run a command with colorized output like `ls`.  I can use the MacOS Terminal themes, but this requires a lot of mouse action every time I open a new one.  I think the trick is to change the *default* colors, but I don't know how to do this from `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS Terminal.app (unless this has changed in *Mohave*) does not recognize the xterm [*dynamic colors*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Commands) feature which would allow you to do this.  iTerm2 does this (but as usual, [*ymmv*](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-ymmv-2483722)).

According to Yoric's lengthy response in [How to have a random background color in Terminal.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348762/how-to-have-a-random-background-color-in-terminal-app), you could use AppleScript to do this.